# How to append LF (0A) character to a file using Path::Tiny?

Tags: perl, append, byte

This approach doesn't work - just string "10" is added

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Path::Tiny qw( path );
use DateTime;

my $d1 = DateTime->new(year => 2019, month => 5, day => 6);
my @lines_to_add;

$lines_to_add[0]= "1|" . $d1->dmy('.') . "|";

$,="\n";
my $filename = "./load";
path($filename)->spew_raw(@lines_to_add);
path($filename)->append({binmode => ":raw"}, 10);
```

I'd like to generate some data and then insert them into a table (Informix running on AIX). However, the environment requires the LF character at the end of files to load from. And I'd like to use just Path::Tiny library for that. (I am on Windows using Strawberry Perl)

Comment: Instead of `10`, you might try `chr(10)` or `"\x0A"`

Comment: oh, that was quite easy, thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value produced by the numerical literal

```
10
```

is being stringified into the two character string

```
10
```

To get a string consisting of character 10, you can use any of the following:

```
"\n"
"\N{LINE FEED}"
"\N{LF}"
"\N{U+000A}"
"\x{0A}"
"\x0A"
"\012"
chr(10)
pack('C', 10)
```

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer!

Comment: In the highly unlikely possibility that anyone cares, `\N{U+00A0}` (and a couple of the others) is the most portable if you care about EBCDIC, since `\x0A` is not the same character there.

Comment: @Grinnz, 1) There aren't many EBCDIC Windows machines, and 2) You have it backwards. The question is specifically about using char 10 instead of the local OS's line endings --the question is about editing a file in a foreign format-- so the last 5 would do exactly what you'd want. (I don't know what `"\n"` the various `\N` versions do on such a machine.)

Comment: @ikegami Generally "I want character 10" is an ASCII-centric concern - if you're working with both ASCII and EBCDIC, you don't work in terms of the bytes they encode to. As such "what you'd want" could be any of those - I also gleaned from the documentation that `\n` may be further translated on EBCDIC to the "NEXT LINE" character, what fun. Regardless, an academic discussion all around.

Comment: @Grinnz, 1) Noone says "I want character 10" when they mean "I want a local line feed", and 2) If the question is really the latter, then forget EBCDIC machines; it's more important to note that none of the answers I provided work on Windows.

Comment: @ikegami Normally they wouldn't, but it should with the `:raw` layer being passed in the OP.

Comment: @Grinnz, Backwards again. You'd have to stop passing it to get a local line ending from the solutions I provided.